# Is there an open source equivalent of ServiceStack AutoQuery for asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, servicestack, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to know if there is an open source equivalent of AutoQuery From ServiceStack for `asp.net` core (or `asp.net`) which can automatic query with the orm i use: ef core (or other) with uris like http://domain.wyz/api/users?ages=16,17,18

I know `OData` and i don't want to use it.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who want, I have started a new project to enable automatic query with asp.net core and ef core :
https://github.com/trenoncourt/AutoQueryable

Answer (score 0):

From the last release [ServiceStack now runs on .NET Core](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.2) where [21 of ServiceStack's most popular NuGet packages](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.2#net-core-servicestack-packages) are available in .NET Core. As part of the release many [existing Live Demos were ported to .NET Core](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.2#net-core-live-demos) including the Live Demos below which make use of [AutoQuery](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms):

- http://northwind.netcore.io
- http://stackapis.netcore.io

Which both have AutoQuery UI plugin enabled:

- http://northwind.netcore.io/ss_admin/autoquery/QueryCustomers
- http://stackapis.netcore.io/ss_admin/autoquery/StackOverflowQuery

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if i understand, if i use AutoQuery, i must use the whole stack of ServiceStack. I have an existing project made with asp.net core and i wan't to add a package like autoquery with a minimal impact on my project.

Comment: @trenoncourt Right but adding ServiceStack to .NET Core isn't as disruptive as ASP.NET, i.e. it's just a module which either handles your request or calls the next .NET Core module in the pipeline. Also AutoQuery requires [very little config to enable](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/StackApis/blob/236ab94004fccc5e8e8be8748882366a34d38ed8/src/StackApis/Startup.cs#L81-L85), i.e. just the `AutoQueryFeature` plugin and your OrmLite DB Connection.